# hash function for well-defined string c++

Tags: c++, hash, hashtable

I have a string which will be exactly consist of numbers between 1-30 and one of 'R','T'or'M' char. Let me illustrate it by some examples.

```
string a="15T","1R","12M","24T","24M" ...  // they are all valid for my string
```

Now I need to have a hash function which gives me a unique hash value for every input string. Since my input have a finite set I think it is possible.

Is there anyone who can tell what kind of hash function could I define ?

By the way, I'll create my hash table using vector therefore I guess size is not an important issue but I'll define 10000 as an upper bound. I mean I assume I can not have more than 10000 such a string

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since you only have 90 distinct values, you can represent each string with a single 7-bit number...

Comment: @KerrekSB yeap, you're so right. If you write it as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks at all

Comment: @eday: Something like `number + (0 if char == 'R' else 30 if char == 'T' else 60)`

Comment: If you can use GNU code, [`gperf`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/) fits your use case perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Just have a large enough integer type and put the (maximal) three characters into the integer:

```
std::size_t hash(const char* s) {
    std::size_t result = 0;
    while(*s) {
        result <<= 8;
        result |= *s++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something along the line of:

```
unsigned myhash(const char * str)
{
    int n = 0;

    // Parse the number part
    for ( ; *str >= '0' && *str <= '9'; ++str)
        n = n * 10 + (*str - '0');

    int c = *str == 'R' ? 0 : 
            *str == 'T' ? 1 :
            *str == 'M' ? 2 :
            3;

    // Check for invalid strings
    if ( c == 3 || n <= 0 || n > 30 || *(++str) != 0 )
    {
        // Some error or anything
        // (Or replace the if condition with an assert)
        throw std::runtime_error("Invalid string");
    }

    // Since 0 <= c < 3 and 0 <= (n-1) < 30
    // There are only 90 possible values
    return c * 30 + (n-1);
}
```

In my experience whenever you have to deal with something like this it is often better to do the opposite, that is work with integers and have a function to perform the opposite conversion if  necessary.

You can rebuild the original string with:

```
int n = hash % 30 + 1;
int c = hash / 30; // 0 is 'R', 1 is 'T', 2 is 'M'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define an algebraic function:

```
result = string[0] * 0x010000  
       + string[1] * 0x000100
       + string[2];
```

Basically, each character fits into an `uint8_t`, which has a range of 256.  So each column is a power of 256.

Yes, there are big gaps, but this insures a unique hash.

You could compress the gaps by using various "powers" for the different character columns.

Given "15T":

```
result = (string[0] - '0') * 10 // 10 == number of digits in the 2nd column  
       + (string[1] - '0') * 3; // 3 == number of choices in 1st column.  
switch (string[2])
{
  case 'T' : result += 0; break;
  case 'M' : result += 1; break;
  case 'R' : result += 2; break;
}
```

It's a number / counting system  where each column has a different number of digits.